# Cake routing table apparently supplemented

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I've inherited a body of code built on the Cake framework and am having difficulty understanding its routing.  I am aware that Cake embodies various conventions which mean that some magic assumptions are made and maybe this is my difficulty.  I am not a Cake expert.

What I want to achieve is a handler for the `/` route as well as various others.  So the routing code looks like this (comments omitted for brevity):

```
    error_log('Route(((');
    Router::connect('/',array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'showoffpage'));
    Router::connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
    Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'admin' => true));
    Router::connect('/:slug',array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'), array('pass' => array('slug')));
    CakePlugin::routes();
    error_log(')))Route -- ' . json_encode(Router::$routes));
```

and when this is encountered, the following is output:

```
[Tue May 14 19:11:19 2019] Route(((
[Tue May 14 19:11:19 2019] )))Route -- [{"keys":[],"options":[],"defaults":{"controller":"users","action":"showoffpage","plugin":null},"template":"\/"},{"keys":[],"options":[],"defaults":{"controller":"users","action":"logout","plugin":null},"template":"\/logout"},{"keys":[],"options":[],"defaults":{"controller":"users","action":"login","admin":true,"prefix":"admin","plugin":null},"template":"\/admin"},{"keys":[],"options":{"pass":["slug"]},"defaults":{"controller":"users","action":"profile","plugin":null},"template":"\/:slug"}]
[Tue May 14 19:11:19 2019] 106.70.102.45:51080 [302]: /
[Tue May 14 19:11:19 2019] Route(((
[Tue May 14 19:11:19 2019] )))Route -- [{"keys":[],"options":[],"defaults":{"controller":"users","action":"showoffpage","plugin":null},"template":"\/"},{"keys":[],"options":[],"defaults":{"controller":"users","action":"logout","plugin":null},"template":"\/logout"},{"keys":[],"options":[],"defaults":{"controller":"users","action":"login","admin":true,"prefix":"admin","plugin":null},"template":"\/admin"},{"keys":[],"options":{"pass":["slug"]},"defaults":{"controller":"users","action":"profile","plugin":null},"template":"\/:slug"}]
[Tue May 14 19:11:19 2019] PROFILE:pages
[Tue May 14 19:11:19 2019] 106.70.102.45:51082 [200]: /pages
```

I.e., the empty route is immediately 'rewritten' as `/pages`, even though the routing table contains only the four entries set up in the code here.  The hit is then dispatched to `UsersController::profile('pages')` (hence the diagnostic `PROFILE:pages` output) rather than `UsersController::showoffpage()`.  There is debugging in `UsersController::showoffpage()` but it is never output.  Obviously I've searched for occurences of the word `pages` in the source, but there are 100s.  What might Cake be doing to make it rewrite the route, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Please post your UsersController. Maybe ```showoffpage```method contain redirect to ```/pages``` or in beforeFilter  method in users or app controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Salines for your comment, because it spurred me to look in the right place.  Method `AppController::_checkAuth()` was performing the redirection because my new route wasn't in a whitelist.